# can I overflow only one div?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I would like to know if I can only have one of my 2 divs being hidden but not the other one 
http://codepen.io/LeaFrontend/pen/yyNbeb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>

.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  top: 90px;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  left: 290px;
}
```

I need to keep the same structure 
Not sure if that is possible

Comment: Are you trying to hide one of the boxes?

Comment: .box1 { display: none; }? Edit the opacity? Push it out of the frame?

Comment: Which of the boxes do you want to overflow so that I'll see if I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do:

**A.** Kill the overflow property in the **.container** block of CSS code.

**B.** Then use the values for top, bottom, left and right properties to make it overflow to the direction that you want.

**C.** Use negative value for for the area you want it to overlap. If you want box1 to overlap to the right by 100px, set the **right property value** -100px.

```
right: -100px;
```